# Copy-Paste hyperlinks from Excel to Outlook but display custom text

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, hyperlink, copy

I use VBA to copy-paste a pivot table from Excel to Outlook. One of the columns is links to certain pages.

I would like to customize it with "Click here" and the hyperlink (instead of sharing the long link).

Answer (score 0):

Alber!

If you are using HTMLBody in your construction Outlook you just need to add an "A" tag.

Sub Send_Email()

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

strHTML = "<a href='http://www.google.com.br'>Click Here</a>"

With OutMail
    .To = "destinatario@gmail.com"
    .CC = "copiado@gmail.com"
    .BCC = "somentesenecessario@gmail.com"
    .HTMLBody = strHTML
    .Subject = "Test e-mail"
    .Display
End With

Set OutApp = Nothing
Set OutMail = Nothing
```

End Sub